# Raspberry Pi 5 Running Ubuntu 23.10 GPIO help needed for Python script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have read that RPi.GPIO does not work with Pi 5.
I can't get gpiozero to work either or gpiod. Has anyone been successful getting gpio to work on Pi 5 running Ubuntu? I would be happy to see a simple program with a button connected to gpio 2, when pressed prints pressed button on screen.

Thanks

Comment: Have you asked that [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I added the switch sensing and actions as per the original question, using the docs sited below as a starting point.

At the time of this reply I have Ubuntu 23.10 up-to-date w/Python 3.11.6.

I have gpiozero 2.0 installed (pip install gpiozero).

Here is what I have running with four LEDs and a simple switch that prints the state of the switch:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from gpiozero import LED, Button
from time import sleep
from signal import signal, SIGINT
from sys import exit

leds = [LED(22), LED(23), LED(24), LED(25)]
button = Button(3)

def sigint_handler(signal_received, frame):
    for led in leds:
        led.off()
    print()
    exit(0)

signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler)

def print_when_pressed():
    print("Button pressed")

def print_when_released():
    print("Button released")

button.when_pressed = print_when_pressed
button.when_released = print_when_released

while True:
    for led in leds:
        led.on()
        sleep(.04)
        led.off()
    sleep(1)
    for led in reversed(leds):
        led.on()
        sleep(.05)
        led.off()
    sleep(1)
```

Notable observations:

- The `while true` loop will run independent of the button sensing.
- Functions are added to the button's callbacks `when_pressed` and `when_released` by value, meaning you don't include the parenthesis. That's why I wrapped the print statements in their on void functions.

For a more complete explanation including a wiring diagram: [enter link description here](https://arcanesciencelab.wordpress.com/2023/12/17/report-3-on-using-ubuntu-23-10-with-a-raspberry-pi-5-blinkin-lights/)
For a check to see if you have proper permissions: [enter link description here](https://arcanesciencelab.wordpress.com/2023/12/16/report-2-on-using-ubuntu-23-10-with-a-raspberry-pi-5-gpio-usage/)
Finially, official gpiozero documentation: [enter link description here](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)